# Product of integer in the list except the integer at that index

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I am trying to do, for example;

given list `[1,7,3,4]`

Output will be like: `[84,12,28,21]` by calculating `[7*3*4, 1*3*4, 1*7*4, 1*7*3]`.

I tried a counter then increase it '`1`' each time, however it doesnt work because sometimes the integer is middle of the list. How can make the algorith of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all elements are non-zero integers, How about taking the product of the complete array and then divide that product by each element? Example -

```
>>> lst = [1,7,3,4]
>>> prod = 1
>>> for i in l:
...     prod *= i
...
>>> newlst = [prod//i for i in lst]
>>> newlst
[84, 12, 28, 21]
```

using `//` for integer division.

To do it in fewer number of lines (2 lines, not taking into account the imports/list definitions, etc) -

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul
>>> lst = [1,7,3,4]

>>> prod = reduce(mul,lst)
>>> newl = [prod//i for i in lst]

>>> newl
[84, 12, 28, 21]
```

Comment: Of course this will only work if all elements are non-zero

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
out = [product(n for i, n in enumerate(in_) if i != index) 
       for _, index in enumerate(in_)]
```

where `product` processes the iterable of numbers to give the total product, e.g.

```
def product(nums):
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, nums, 1)
```

Comment: This uses N*(N-1) multiply operations which is O(N^2), whereas the other approach only does 2N.

Comment: @smci you're right, although straightforward this approach is relatively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

My technique is similar to Anand S Kumar's (but I did write this when there was only 1 other answer here :) ). Multiplying all the elements & then dividing by each element to create the output list is much more efficient than performing n-1 multiplications for each of n elements, especially when n is large.

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def lagrange(seq):
    #Find the product of all elements
    prod = reduce(mul, seq, 1)
    return [prod // i for i in seq]

a = [1, 7, 3, 4]
print a, lagrange(a)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print a, lagrange(a)
```

**output**

```
[1, 7, 3, 4] [84, 12, 28, 21]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [720, 360, 240, 180, 144, 120]
```

In Python 2 `reduce()` is built-in, but you can import it from functools; in Python 3 it's only available if you import it from functools.

FWIW, I named the function lagrange because the process reminded me of [Lagrange polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: @AnandSKumar: Thanks for the module name correction! I didn't realise `reduce()` was available as an import in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
import itertools
import operator

a = [1,7,3,4]

[reduce(operator.mul, i, 1) for i in itertools.combinations(a, len(a) - 1)][::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers=[2,3,0]
arr=np.ndarray(len(numbers),int)
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    arr[i]= np.prod(numbers[i+1:])*np.prod(numbers[0:i])
print(arr)
```